# Cleaner jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I'm tinkering with some jquery and I'll like to know if there is a better way of writing the following block of code. It just looks "unclean" to me but hey, it works

```
$('#login-form-click').click(function(e) {
    $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#register-form-click').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault(); });

$('#register-form-click').click(function(e) {
    $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-click').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault(); });

$('#lost-pass-click').click(function(e) {
    $("#lost-pass-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-click-2').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();});

$('#login-form-click-2').click(function(e) {
    $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#lost-pass-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-click-2').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault(); });
```

Any advice it's much appreciated.

Thanks, everyone ;)

Comment: This question is offtopic on stackoverflow. Try on another stackexchange community like Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . I vote to close this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a good candidate to move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry my bad!!!

Comment: No problem :) I wish you will be helped on code review ;)